# how to get unicode text from jtextpane java

Tags: java, html, swing, unicode, jtextpane

I have set the jtextpane content type as html and setted the

```
    ta_description = new JTextPane();
    ta_description.setContentType("text/html");
    ta_description.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    ta_description.setText("<![CDATA[<br>வேலூர் மாவட்டம், அணைக்கட்டு 
        தொகுதி பா.ம.க.வை சேர்ந்த கலையரசு எம்.எல்.ஏ. நேற்று முன்தினம் 
        காலை முதல்-அமைச்சர் ஜெயலலிதாவை சந்தித்து தனது தொகுதி 
        பிரச்சினைகள் குறித்து பேசினார். அதைத்தொடர்ந்து அவரை கட்சியில் 
        இருந்து நீக்குவதாக பா.ம.க. தலைவர் ஜி.கே.மணி அறிவித்தார்.<br>]]>);
```

When i get this text using ta_description.gettext() and it will be like as below

<![CDATA[<html>
  <head>

</head>
  <body>
    <br>
    &#2997;&#3015;&#2994;&#3010;&#2992;&#3021; &#2990;&#3006;&#2997;&#2975;&#3021;&#2975;&#2990;&#3021;, &#2949;&#2979;&#3016;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#2975;&#3021;&#2975;&#3009; &#2980;&#3018;&#2965;&#3009;&#2980;&#3007; &#2986;&#3006;.&#2990;.&#2965;.&#2997;&#3016; &#2970;&#3015;&#2992;&#3021;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980; &#2965;&#2994;&#3016;&#2991;&#2992;&#2970;&#3009; &#2958;&#2990;&#3021;.&#2958;&#2994;&#3021;.&#2959;. 
    &#2984;&#3015;&#2993;&#3021;&#2993;&#3009; &#2990;&#3009;&#2985;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2985;&#2990;&#3021; &#2965;&#3006;&#2994;&#3016; &#2990;&#3009;&#2980;&#2994;&#3021;-&#2949;&#2990;&#3016;&#2970;&#3021;&#2970;&#2992;&#3021; &#2972;&#3014;&#2991;&#2994;&#2994;&#3007;&#2980;&#3006;&#2997;&#3016; &#2970;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3009; &#2980;&#2985;&#2980;&#3009; &#2980;&#3018;&#2965;&#3009;&#2980;&#3007; 
    &#2986;&#3007;&#2992;&#2970;&#3021;&#2970;&#3007;&#2985;&#3016;&#2965;&#2995;&#3021; &#2965;&#3009;&#2993;&#3007;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3009; &#2986;&#3015;&#2970;&#3007;&#2985;&#3006;&#2992;&#3021;. &#2949;&#2980;&#3016;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3018;&#2975;&#2992;&#3021;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3009; &#2949;&#2997;&#2992;&#3016; &#2965;&#2975;&#3021;&#2970;&#3007;&#2991;&#3007;&#2994;&#3021; &#2951;&#2992;&#3009;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3009; 
    &#2984;&#3008;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#3009;&#2997;&#2980;&#3006;&#2965; &#2986;&#3006;.&#2990;.&#2965;. &#2980;&#2994;&#3016;&#2997;&#2992;&#3021; &#2972;&#3007;.&#2965;&#3015;.&#2990;&#2979;&#3007; &#2949;&#2993;&#3007;&#2997;&#3007;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3006;&#2992;&#3021;.<br>
  </body>
</html>
]]>

I saw this is Tamil Unicode Characters from http://www.utf.ru/tables/tamil.html

I need to get text correctly and i dono how to get text properly.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses font from the system , so if the system doesn't contain a specific font then you can deploy that font within your application using Font.createFont().
So if you donot have Tamil font download it [here](http://www.azhagi.com/freefonts.html)

First thing you have to do is get a Tamil unicode supported font. Somthing like this:

```
Font tamil =new Font("Latha", Font.BOLD,15);//I had a font Latha which supports tamil font
```

Then set the font of your JTextPane :

```
ta_description.setFont(tamil);
```

[image: See how it looks in my system]

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Font TamilFont=new Font("Latha", Font.BOLD,15);
        textPane.setFont(TamilFont);



    }

}
```

Comment: sir.. i need to get the text from this textpane using gettext()....am able to set text but gettext is the problem here

Comment: And how you are using the gettext() string? are you populating it in some field? Please post a MCVE.

Comment: i used ta_description.getText() which gives above mentioned unicode output. I used setcontenttype("text/html") bit i dono how to get that unicode font correctly